# Sometime publishing getting failed with error "You do not have permission to perform this action"

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

After upgrade from Tridion 5.3 to Tridion 2011 SP1, when we publish any page it is getting failed with error "You do not have permission to perform this action" Preview of pages is working fine.  We tried to check exactly in which stage issue is coming but after double click on failed transaction it just shows the error message under "Publishing Process Details" Tab.  I am Administrator in Tridion CMS. Is it related to configuration of cd_deployer_conf or cd_storage_conf.?

It seems that issue is related to user access getting below error message on CME server in cd_Transport.log
An unexpected error occurred while polling: IP:PORT/httpupload.aspx reason: Unauthorized

In event log on CME getting below error : 
You do not have permission to perform this action.
Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

Answer (score 5):

There is something wrong with your permissions on the HttpUpload app.  Make sure that the user it's executing as has permissions to the Content Deployer location for incoming content.

Do this by checking the Application Pool's identity to see what user it is.  IIS 7.5 uses ApplicationPoolIdentity as the default user, which is changed from previous versions where the default was NetworkService ([here](http://blogs.iis.net/webdevelopertips/archive/2009/10/02/tip-98-did-you-know-the-default-application-pool-identity-in-iis-7-5-windows-7-changed-from-networkservice-to-apppoolidentity.aspx) is a little more about that).  If you set the app pool's identify back to what you used in 5.3, it should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

The error suggests that there is a permissions problem for the user(may be NetworkService) writing the files on behalf of the SDL Tridion Content Delivery Deployer.

If you are unsure of which user is writing files on behalf of the SDL Tridion Content Delivery Deployer then you should be able to use a file system monitoring application such as Process Monitor (available from Microsoft TechNet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) - please run this, reproduce the issue and then look for 'Access Denied' events.

This should let you know which user is performing the write action - provide this user with access to write to the directory and see if error disappear.

Comment: Does Network Service User write the content to files ? or the user we configure in Publication Target writes the content to Files system.  We have user called TridionServiceUser configured in publication target.

Comment: The user which you have set in the HTTP Deployer Application pool identity. You can confirm the user by running the Process Monitor utility.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help, according to SDL LiveContent

> The new TOM.NET API is still functionally a read-only interface during rendering and publishing. That is, you cannot create, update or delete Content Manager items while your Template is executing. This behaviour also applies to the now deprecated TOM API, meaning that if you have Templates that use the TOM API and perform write actions, these Templates will now fail.
>
> If you do want your old TOM templates to be able to write to the Content Manager, you can configure the Content Manager to allow writing during rendering and publishing. You enable Templates to write to the Content Manager as by opening the Tridion Content Manager configuration file `<Tridion.ContentManager.config>` (located in the config sub-folder of the Tridion Content Manager root location), and adding an attribute `<allowWriteOperationsInTemplates>`, set to true, to the element called `<tridion.contentmanager.security>`.

Source: ["Backwards compatibility issues in Content Manager" page on SDL LiveContent](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_1453B827EA0C4607BA8A68AAB2E95CCC)

Comment: Post a link to where you've got the quote, as well.